# Virtualization Software for Windows

Tags: windows, virtualization

I'm searching a good and reliable virtualization software for Windows 8/8.1 and therefor for Windows 10 too (which shouldn't be that hard, as it will work on Windwos 8).

I know [VMWare](https://www.vmware.com/) and [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/).
Currently I'm not sure if I want to buy VMWare, as it's not that cheap and on the other hand VirtualBox is great, but it has some errors or misbehavior especially if you run a team of virtual machines.

Is there any competitive software which is ideally OpenSource and runs good on Windows?

**Requirements:**

- Runs on Windows
- Has support for virtual teams (means: build a virtual network between just those teamed machines)
- It should be able to run multiple VMs at the same time (10+)
- Ideally some filesharing addition. An easy way to get data into the vm or out of it (like the VMWare Additions).
- optional: It would be great if the software adds recommendations for the OS your trying to install (minimum ram, etc.)
- optional: Automatic setup (just throw the ISO into the VM, give the needed information at the start (username, pw, etc.)) and the setup will be executed by the software

Comment: Depending what you are trying to do it might be worth taking a look at Docker. http://docs.docker.com

Comment: Yes docker can be some sort of solution. But I don't think it will meet my needs. I use the VMs for example as a Container to run my DEV-Tools and don't pollute my Host with many different coding environments. And in some cases I need to run Linux tools on my Windows Host (like Django)

Comment: I suggest you make sure you have the newest version of VirtualBox, and if the issue persist, then file a bug report)if you haven't).  Maybe they will get fixed.

Comment: Might be more cost-effective and convenient to outsource this something like [Microsoft Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/)

Comment: If you have enough resources on your machine, you could run a very well equipped VM with a hypervisor like VMware's ESXi and then run your other virtual platforms on top of that.